# move background object actionscript 3 middle

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I am currently making a 2d game for Android.

I am now having a trouble with the movement of my character.

Here's what I want to do:

1. when i touch the button left / right the HERO should walk to his left/right.
2. IF the HERO is not in the MIDDLE of the STAGE, he should proceed to walk UNTIL he reaches the MIDDLE of the STAGE.
3. When he reached the MIDDLE of the STAGE.  Instead of the HERO, I want the BACKGROUND to move.

Could you please tell me how should I validate the code, so that when (HERO.x = middle of the stage) the background starts to move?

Thank You :) and here's the code snippets for the right button which doesn't work as expected.

```
btnright.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN,onright);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,goright);


function onright(e:TouchEvent):void{
    istouching = true;
}

function goright(e:Event):void{

    if(istouching){ //if the button is touched
        hero.x+=10;
        hero.gotoAndStop("walking");
        hero.scaleX=1;

        if(hero.x == stage.stageWidth*.5){ //if HERO reaches the middle of the stage
            bg.x-=5;
            hero.gotoAndStop("walking");
            hero.scaleX=1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are always moving the hero on touch! and your "if equal to center" statement fires only on 1 pixel, you need "greater then"

```
if(istouching){ //if the button is touched

    hero.gotoAndStop("walking");
    hero.scaleX=1;

    if(hero.x > stage.stageWidth*.5){ //if HERO reaches the middle of the stage
        bg.x-=5;

    }else{
        hero.x+=10;
     }
}
```